# Mule Expression block not working?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Here is what my flow looks like.

[image]

In the "Expression" settings, I simply have the following:

```
key != 0
```

The filename/pattern for the file connector is **#[key]**

It is still outputting a file named 0 which contains the email body.  It does also output all other attachments properly.  I just don't want it to write the email body to a file.  What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:imap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap"
       xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
       xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
       xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.6/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/3.6/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap/3.6/mule-imap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/3.6/mule-email.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.6/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd" version="EE-3.6.0">

    <imap:connector name="imapConnector" checkFrequency="10000" doc:name="IMAP" /> 

    <expression-transformer name="returnAttachments" doc:name="Expression">
        <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*"/>
    </expression-transformer>

    <file:connector name="fileName" doc:name="File"> 
        <file:expression-filename-parser/> 
    </file:connector>
    <flow name="incoming-orders">
        <imap:inbound-endpoint host="server" port="143" user="user" password="pass" disableTransportTransformer="true" transformer-refs="returnAttachments" doc:name="IMAP"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" counterVariableName="i" rootMessageVariableName="msg">
            <expression-component doc:name="Expression">key != 0</expression-component>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\Mule\in" outputPattern="#[key]" doc:name="File" responseTimeout="10000">
                <expression-transformer> 
                    <return-argument expression="payload.inputStream" evaluator="groovy"/> 
                </expression-transformer>
            </file:outbound-endpoint>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `foreach` is processing the **values** of the `inboundAttachments`map so you don't get keys. I suggest something like:

`<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[message.inboundAttachments.entrySet()]">
    <expression-transformer doc:name="Expression" expression="#[payload.key != 0]"/>
    ...
    </foreach>`

Now you'll process key-value pairs so you might need to use a `set-payload` to send just `payload.value`, saving the key before in a variable to use in the file endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I just downloaded Mule a few days ago, so I'm still learning.  I'll see if this helps.

Comment: I understand and no problem, you're checking the docs so that's a good start to learn!